# how do you remove the navigation bar on Android?

Tags: android

When I listen to a YouTube video fullscreen in landscape on my Galaxy Nexus, the navigation bar on the right disapear after a few seconds (the bar which contains the "back", "home" and "recent apps" buttons ).

I want to do the same thing when a user watch a video in my app. What is the code to hide the navigation bar?

---

[UPDATE] Here is the bar I want to hide. Not the title bar, nor the action bar. The navigation bar. (the bar which contains the "back", "home" and "recent apps" buttons ). I also don't want to "dim" the buttons. I'm looking into removing the bar entirely (like the YouTube app does when you plan a video fullscreen in landscape mode)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? From where are you going to take the view? From the Activity?
Moreover, is this flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` only for the ICS Android version? Or it is present as well in HoneyComb?

Comment: @2dvisio SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is for level 14 and up only (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION). And you can take any view in the screen to set this flag)

Comment: Thanks. It seems like for Version 3.x there's no chance of doing the same thing..

Comment: hi.. scuse me if i reopen question... i try to add that to a Handler that every 3000 millisec recall that method to have bar "always" hided. it works only on app startup then no.. how can i do?

Answer (score 3):

The last information I have is that you can use the black tape to cover it. That's the suggestion given by Chet Haase. Watch [this google IO 2011 session Q&A](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/honeycomb-highlights.html) starting at 53minutes

Youtube app also dim it, not remove it. It is called light out mode.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` flag can be used on a View to hide the navigation bar until a user interaction occurs, **starting from** [Android API 14](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

You should look at [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#UI) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION).

Answer (score 1):

This code will hide the navigation bar until you swipe down from the status bar. It's the same method that Jetpack Joyride uses:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); 
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

You must also have this in the activity section of your XML file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is set System Ui Visibility in `onResume()`

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

If you wont set it sticky bar will be visible again when touch screen will be occured

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

That will do the trick. Also check out the HoneycombGallery example which demonstrates this working.

Comment: I want to hide the navigation bar, not the action bar.

Comment: Apologies. You cannot remove, but you can hide. Try this View v = findViewById(R.id.myview);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);

Comment: This will "dim" the button - not hide them. It should be possible to remove the navigation bar since the YouTube app does it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to hide the navigation bar and it works perfectly for me

```
View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();

v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.